# How to change the login screen keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout, dvorak

I switched from Qwerty to Dvorak, but the login screen still uses Qwerty.

How can I configure the login screen to use Dvorak?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Ubuntu / Natty, edit the file /etc/default/keyboard, look for the XKBVARIANT setting, and set it to this:

```
XKBVARIANT="dvorak"
```

This will tell GDM, the login manager, which keyboard layout to use per default.

Note: the comments in the file warn that this only takes effect after udev is restarted; I would just reboot the machine after changing it.

Comment: This helped me with another problem. While I kept removing the Qwerty keyboard from my keyboard preferences, after I rebooted it always showed up again. I then removed it from the /etc/default/keyboard file as you said and I now no longer have the problem.

Comment: I can confirm this still works on Trusty. In fact it seems to be the only way to change the login screen keyboard layout.