# How do I change the login manager's keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout, login-screen

I have a netbook with an AZERTY layout. I've changed it to "bépo" to try it, but now I've reset it to a french layout.

While all the apps have taken the change into account, Ubuntu's login manager still uses bépo, making entering passwords a challenge. I've enabled the virtual keyboard for the time being so that I could login again.

I don't remember what I had done in the first place to switch the login screen to bépo, but now I can't switch it back.

[image]

**EDIT** : In the keyboard settings page, if I click "use system defaults", then everything is in bépo ! Where is this different keyboard layout set ?

**ANOTHER EDIT** : Here's what did not work :

1. Changing the layout in settings
2. using the "use system defaults" checkbox in settings
3. sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
4. changing it in Xconf
5. adding a line in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
6. sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
7. slaming head against desk
8. dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
9. sudo gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts "['fr']"
10. combinations of the above

[image]

Is it possible to relaunch the keyboard configuration tool that's in ubuntu's setup ? The thing has automatic layout detection and it changes the setting everywhere.

Comment: maybe try to switch your keyboard with this command : sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration  , or did i missunderstand something ?

Comment: I had tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm, will try yours now

Comment: Nope, it's still the same keyboard at the login screen.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please accept it. (even if it's your own)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Must have been a weird `lightdm` bug.

`Lightdm` got the new keyboard layout once I changed the login manager to `gdm`, then back to `lightdm`, even though simply doing `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` did nothing.

So here it is :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

(set gdm as the login manager when asked)

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

(set it as the login manager when asked)

```
sudo apt-get remove gdm
```

Then, restart.

Changing a keyboard layout in linux is serious business.

Answer (score 12):

What did seem to work for me was [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/49658/1116): change `/etc/default/keyboard`.

*Banging head on desk* indeed, this is ridiculous.

Comment: This did work for me, on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: You can find more info or examles how to configure at http://www.xfree86.org/current/XKB-Config2.html#3

Comment: This is a bad solution for people switching between different layouts.

Answer (score 5):

From [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), run the following command to set the language layouts (you can set maximum four layouts) for your lightdm login screen:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts "['us\taltgr-intl', 'fr']"
```

With the above command you set English (International) and French layouts, but you can change them as you wish.

To see the current layouts, you can use:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts
```

Now, you should be able to use the keyboard icon from the top-right of your screen:

[image: keyboard icon]

Next is a screen capture from my login screen (I used `gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts "['us\taltgr-intl', 'gr', 'ro']"` in terminal). As you can see, I can change the language layout as I wish:

[image: login screen]

Comment: I thought of that of course, only "french/bépo" appears in that list.

Comment: @Manu Why don't you add another one keyboard layout?

Comment: I keep doing that, the layout at the login screen are not the same as the layouts once logged in

Comment: @Manu Then use this command from terminal to set layouts (you can set maximum four layouts): `gsettings set org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts "['us\taltgr-intl', 'fr']"` (for English - International and French). To see the current layouts, use: `gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts`

Comment: I tried "['fr']" but that did not work. Problem is the layout is already in French, but in the wrong variant.

Comment: @Manu Are you sure? Check with `gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts` . Log out and log in back.

Comment: "get" returns "['fr']"... maybe it was that + dpkg-reconfigure

Comment: @Manu No, ...nothing to do with `dpkg-reconfigure` in my opinion. Maybe you have tested them in the same time, but I'm sure that this method has done the job. This is the right method.

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty, thank you for the detailed answer. If someone has the same problem, note that this solution *seemed* to work only once I reconfigured lightdm, see my own answer bellow.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on Trusty.

Comment: I tried this in Ubuntustudio 14.04 (trusty), but the command outputs "No such schema 'org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard'".

Answer (score 3):

What helped me was to enter shell <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> and close lightdm

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

then

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and

```
sudo service keyboard-setup restart
```

I ran those commands as user and as root, then when I started `lightdm`

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

the keyboard was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Make a short-key in **System Settings > Keyboard Layout > Options** under **"key(s) to change layout"** to switch layouts.

You can see detailed answer here [Keyboard shortcut for Lockscreen not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126782/keyboard-shortcut-for-lockscreen-not-working)

Comment: The layout change key doesn't seem to have any effect on the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

In GNOME 42 running GDM login manager, `localectl` told me `VC Keymap: n/a`.

Running `sudo localectl set-x11-keymap dk` set the login screen layout to Danish.

I have no input source selection available under Region & Languages > Login Screen.

See further [this GNOME help page](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/keyboard-layout.html.en)

Comment: The Input Source section has been moved to Settings -> Keyboard in later Ubuntu versions, and the GUI way still works.