# How can I change the Keyboard Layout on login screen?

Tags: password, keyboard-layout, users, login-screen

I changed my Keyboard Layout from Swedish to English, but now my password doesn’t work and I can’t login. I need a way to change the keyboard layout at the login screen without having access to the keyboard or a way to enter the password using characters not available on the keyboard itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the login manager's keyboard layout?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328952/how-do-i-change-the-login-managers-keyboard-layout)

Answer (score 30):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch console mode. Type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and also now type your password.
- Next type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  type your password again and follow screen instruction.

As usual, it will prompt you for the model of keyboard (what the keyboard *is*), and then for the keyboard layout (what the keys should *do*)

To apply new settings, restarting the keyboard-setup service with this

```
 sudo service keyboard-setup restart
```

Comment: But how am I supposed to type `sudo service keyboard-setup restart` if I can't login because of the layout

Comment: Why switch to console mode? Can't I just open a terminal?

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + F3` for switching to console mode in Ubuntu 18.04
https://askubuntu.com/a/1053220/726213

Comment: This worked specifically when most x.org settings (`setxkbmap` and `localectl ...` would not persist after restarts with Kali. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've ben looking for this solution for a long time. Really appreciate your answer. Many thanks!

Comment: I know this thread is old, but maybe the people are still around ;) Is there a way to add a second keyboard? This solution replaces the existing layout

Comment: To answer some questions from the comments: Depending on how/where OP set the layout, this change only affects the desktop session, but not the tty consoles (where the login screen gets its layout from depends on the flavor of Ubuntu). Hence we need `Ctrl + Alt + F3` to switch to a tty console, which (hopefully) still has the Swedish layout so OP can enter their password. Of course one could run these commands from a terminal, but only after you manage to log into a desktop session.

Comment: This also works on **encrypted disk password login screen**. Thank you !

Comment: @CedricMartens For me the only way was to figure out what layout I'm stuck with and adjust my keystrokes accordingly. One can switch the password field to cleartext mode and press the topleft-most six keys. In my case, instead of the expected QWERTZ there appeared AZERTY, so I knew it must be a French variant. I just googled "azerty" and with the help of [a layout map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_France.svg) managed to type my password.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:
Change de variable **XKBVARIANT** = “us”, on file **/etc/default/keyboard**
to the name of layout you want and reboot.

Comment: For me it was a french "afnor" and I switched to "azerty". It was a shot in the dark however, I wonder where one could find a list of all available variants

Comment: you can try ```localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts``` or ```localectl list-x11-keymap-variants```

Comment: That's excatly what I meant ! Thanks !

Comment: @AxelB The file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst` contains a list of all available variants. Source: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/keyboard.5.html#files (and tried it myself)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but recently I have faced with the same issue and the solution above did not help.

During the Linux Mint installation, I accidentally selected the wrong keyboard layout. Later I fixed it by removing the old one and adding the proper keyboard, but unfortunately, this had no impact on the login screen.

Solution:

1. login and show your current, working layout configuration with `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`
2. check the layout that is used on the login screen: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`
3. set up properly the login screen keyboard layout with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

That was the only solution that worked for me.
I hope that it helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's been facing the same problem and nothing worked here's an idea boot from the recovery mode then scroll down to root then write the following command to reset your password "passwd yourUserName" then enter your new password for that username hope this helps :)

Comment: Wouldn’t it be possible to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` in recovery mode and revert to a keyboard layout that has all the characters needed for recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use tty3 using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
2. `sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard` to look like this:

   ```bash
   # KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

   # Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

   XKBMODEL="macbook78"<br>
   XKBLAYOUT="de"<br>
   XKBVARIANT="basic"<br>
   XKBOPTIONS=""<br>

   BACKSPACE="guess"
   ```
3. `sudo setupcon`
4. `reboot`

After that it changed my layout.

Comment: Kali is off-topic here.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. The accepted answer didn't work for me but changing `sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard` with `XKBLAYOUT="de"` did the trick (with a restart)

Answer (score 0):

In GNOME 42, `localectl` told me `VC Keymap: n/a`.

Running `sudo localectl set-x11-keymap dk` set the login screen layout to Danish.

I have no input source selection available under Region & Languages > Login Screen.

See further [this GNOME help page](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/keyboard-layout.html.en)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on Ubuntu 22. On the login screen click on the accessibility options and activate the screen keyboard, then you should be able to get your special character and login.

Then once logged in, you should be able to do the proper configuration described by the other answers.