# Ubuntu 18.04 not accepting password

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, password, onscreen-keyboard

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 my password is no longer being accepted on the login screen. The funny thing is that the password is accepted through the terminal and when I enter it using the on-screen accessibility keyboard. I am able to login through this on-screen accessibility keyboard but it's incredibly annoying. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the login screen doesn't recognise the keyboard layout. Everything worked when I switched the layout to the standard US, however, this was really inconvenient since I am not using a standard US keyboard. After a bit of digging, I found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514284/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-layout-on-login-screen). The steps are as follows:

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
2. `sudo service keyboard-setup restart`