# How to change keyboard layout permanently?

Tags: keyboard, language-support

I tried to change my keyboard layout to german:

```
loadkeys de
```

But this is only temporary, if I reboot, then it it set back to english again...
I tried to make it permanent:

```
localectl set-keymap de
```

but I get, "localectl : command not found"

Answer (score 1):

you could try to manually modify `sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard`

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put it into your bashrc, if it located in your default directory it will be:

```
echo loadkeys de >> ~/.bashrc
```

If it does not work you can try using rc.local which run just before the login screen, be careful I never tried this but it should be fine:

create or open the file rc.local with your favorite editor like `nano /etc/rc.local`

Then paste this text

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

loadkeys de
exit 0
```

then give it the proper right `chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

Comment: That works, but it only works after login. So I have to take care at the login... is there a better solution?

Comment: Try with setxkbmap de instead of loadkeys de

Comment: I get `cannot open display "default display"`

Comment: Here is a similar question to your problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/514284/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-layout-on-login-screen

Comment: Does not work either. I tried `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and get  **"keyboard-configuration" not installed and no info available**

Comment: I edited my initial post

Comment: @Black: If neither `localectl` nor `keyboard-configuration` is installed, I have to ask which Ubuntu version you are using.