# Keyboard Layout Login Screen

Tags: keyboard-layout, login-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. I changed my password to one which is not even in the Latin alphabet. How can I change the keyboard layout on the login screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the Keyboard Layout on login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514284/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-layout-on-login-screen)

Comment: See the existing question. Apparently, there is no decent graphical ui to change that.