# Cannot login because of other keyboard on login screen

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, login

I had changed my password using bg symbols in my password to make it more secure, but when I restart to kubuntu login lightdm screen there is no way to return to bg symbols because the default layout is us. Login to cntr+alt+f6 is not a way because I canot change the layout from there neither. There is also not screen keyboard. I can only use the guest session for downloading something. 
Please help

Comment: Ubuntu is plagued of bugs with non-US layouts, since 13.10 (just a quick search on launchpad will confirm this). have you tried if some of the answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/328952/how-do-i-change-the-login-managers-keyboard-layout can help you?

Comment: Otherwise, follow http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password and set a password with US-only chars.

Comment: logging as guest and setting bg as first layout , going in cntr+alt+f6 and loging from there solves the problem (alt+shift now works in the virtual terminal). Thank you

Comment: @Rmano: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)