# What is Ubuntu mate login manager

Tags: login, ubuntu-mate

I'd like to change the keyboard configuration of the login manager of Ubuntu Mate, and for this I need to find the configuration file.

But I don't know what is the login manager.

So what is the ubuntu-mate login manager, or where can I find this info ?

EDIT: My problem is different as the one suggested, because none of theses solutions work for me.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Although your question shows value, and we would like to help you, and assist you to better optimize Ubuntu, to do so, we will need some more information about your question specifically. For example: any references that could be made, any terminal outputs, or screenshots. If you need to know what kind of information we need, please leave a comment. Once you have gathered that information, please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/738146/edit) your question, and add this info. Thanks :)

Comment: hum... I'm just asking for the name of the graphical tool which is used to login in Ubuntu-mate. So I don't know what kind of reference you want, and I don't have any terminal outputs. For the screen-shot I thought to make one, but I don't know how to do this in the login screen. Thanks ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the login manager's keyboard layout?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328952/how-do-i-change-the-login-managers-keyboard-layout)

Comment: POSSIBLE ^ Not sure if changes were made between releases of Ubuntu. Please try that solution, and if it works, we will close this question

Comment: @Phantom you should be able to tell what login manager it is simply by looking at the image you see ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind, I'm sorry if I don't know all login managers, and all of there themes

Comment: @Phantom oh there are not that many. All our versions probably all use lightdm so that is 1 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic info on configuring LightDM: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

And the following page explains how to change keyboard layout on the login screen (Lightdm GTK+ Greeter) in Ubuntu MATE:
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-set-keyboard-layout-on-login-screen/1405

So, in **Lightdm GTK+ Greeter Settings > Panel** you can add the keyboard layout indicator by which you can change the default keyboard layout:

[image]

Also, add the following lines to **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf** in order to set default keyboard layout (French in this example):

```
[Seat:*]
display-setup-script = setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout fr
```