# How to change the log in keyboard layout in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: keyboard, login, keyboard-layout, login-screen, input-language

I'm a former windows user and completly new to linux and ubuntu (I had no idea what kernel, or booted, or distro was until a day ago). I just installed it to try it out. I am however not able to change the keyboard layout in the log in screen (I had to click on many keys to finally be able to get the password that I wanted). It was not obvious for me which keyboard to choose during the installation process (I tried French AZERTY, since there was no Belgian AZERTY option, and the French AZERTY was also different from my keyboard, so I went for USA English).

However, later after the intallation of ubuntu, I was able to change in settings to Belgian keyboard layout. So, now I can type normally with my Belgian AZERTY keyboard on the browser or in the Terminal. However, this change was not applied to the log in screen.

The Log-in screen is now in AZERTY, but not the Belgian format of my keyboard (but the Belgian keyboard is activated once I log-in).

Can someone guide me? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks like there is a solution here https://askubuntu.com/questions/328952/how-do-i-change-the-login-managers-keyboard-layout?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I got in a similar situation after installing Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (default to English) on a laptop and using the GUI to select the French keyboard layout afterwards: login screen kept on using English while French was used everywhere else. Among fixes suggested in various places this is the simple one which worked for me: change XKBLAYOUT from "us" to "fr" ("be" for you) in the file /etc/default/keyboard.
This is how to do it step by step (assuming you are still a Linux beginner):

1. from the GUI open a terminal window with CTRL+ALT+t
2. type 'cd /etc/default' then ENTER
3. type 'sudo nano keyboard' then ENTER
4. enter root password to get into nano text editor
5. navigate within the text and modify it to obtain XKBLAYOUT="be"
6. type CTRL+x, answer y (for 'Yes') then ENTER to confirm file name ('keyboard')
7. reboot